# xfbml registration plugin validation error

Tags: facebook, plugins, registration, xfbml

I used Facebook's demo scripts to understand registration plugin' system. I use this code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=285180546708&xfbml=1"></script>

<fb:registration redirect-uri="http://basarozcan.com/store_userdata.php"
  fields='[{"name":"name"},
           {"name":"username","description":"Username","type":"text"}]'
  onvalidate="validate_async"></fb:registration>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function validate_async(form, cb) {
        $.getJSON('validate.php?username=' + form.username,
    function (response) {
        if (response.error) {
            // Username isn't taken, let the form submit
            cb();
        }
        cb({ username: 'That username is taken' });
    });
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I opened the page and write username but script can not validate username and firebug show an error. Error is:

```
Permission denied to access property 'Arbiter'
if (p == parent || !p.Arbiter || !p.JSON) {
```

How can I solve this problem? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use HTTPS:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=285180546708&xfbml=1"></script>
```